# Preventing activity from reusing entrance scene transition for exit

Tags: java, android

Currently I'm starting an activity using:

`Bundle bundle = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(getActivity(),
     new Pair<View, String>(recyclerView.getLayoutManager().findViewByPosition(position)
     .findViewById(R.id.albumView), "albumArt"),
     new Pair<View, String (recyclerView.getLayoutManager().findViewByPosition(position)
     .findViewById(R.id.infoView), "underbar"))
     .toBundle();
startActivity(intent, bundle);`

It transitions in fine but on pressing back it tries to do the reverse transition, when I want it to use a different animation altogether. How would you go about cancelling the transition so an animation could be used instead?

Answer (score 0):

I know its a little late but, if someone still needs to do this. You can do this by postponing the enter transition on activity reenter and overriding remaining transitions with a transition that does nothing and than restart the postponed transition. Now, you can use any custom animation you want